# ClassInitialize of base class runs after TestClass of inheriting class

Tags: c#, inheritance, mstest

I have a TestClass that uses a variable OutputPath:

```
[TestClass]
public class InheritingTest : BaseTestClass
    {
        
        public static string path = OutputPath + "Prefs.pref";
```

this variable is defined in the base class (and there is value in the testContext.Properties for it):

```
public class BaseTestClass
    {

        public static string OutputPath;
        public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

        [ClassInitialize()]
        public static void Initialize(TestContext testContext)
        {
            InitConnection(testContext);
            OutputPath = testContext.Properties["OutputPath"].ToString();
        }
```

but for some reason on my local machine when the TestClass runs the value of OutputPath is null, so the value of path is only "Prefs.pref" and only after that the ClassInitialize is running and the value of OutputPath is changed, and even weirder is that on a colleague machine it works fine.
Can anybody explain to me what can cause the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: The `ClassInitialize` attribute guarantees that the method runs before any test method. But it has no such guarantee on other methods and initializers.

Comment: I would change path to a property getting the path lazily `public static string path => OutputPath + "Prefs.pref";`